# angular2, angular-cli, underscore and TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4_underscore__.now is not a function

Tags: angular, underscore.js

I am having a terrible time trying pot get underscore to work with angular2 with angular-cli.

```
npm install underscore --save
npm install --save @types/underscore
typings install dt~underscore --global --save
```

Then:

```
import * as _ from 'underscore';

ngOnInit(){
      console.log (_.now());
}

error_handler.js:45 EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4_underscore__.now is not a function

zone.js:355 Unhandled Promise rejection: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4_underscore__.now is not a function ; Zone: angular ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4_underscore__.now is not a function(…) TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4_underscore__.now is not a function
    at DashboardComponent.ngOnInit (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:53385:68)
    at _View_DashboardComponent_Host0.detectChangesInternal (DashboardComponent_Host.ngfactory.js:40:87)
    at _View_DashboardComponent_Host0.AppView.detectChanges (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:73399:14)
    at _View_DashboardComponent_Host0.DebugAppView.detectChanges (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:73504:44)
    at ViewRef_.detectChanges (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:46245:20)
    at RouterOutlet.activate (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:52965:42)
    at ActivateRoutes.placeComponentIntoOutlet (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:24392:16)
    at ActivateRoutes.activateRoutes (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:24370:22)
    at http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:24332:19
    at Array.forEach (native)
```

typings.json

```
{
  "globalDependencies": {
    "underscore": "registry:dt/underscore#1.8.3+20160908111004"
  }
}
```

This is in package.json

```
  "underscore": "^1.8.3",
```

angular-cli.json

```
"scripts": [
        ...,
        "../node_modules/underscore/underscore.js"
      ],
```

Comment: fyi upraded to lodash which works out of the box